# Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?

Tags: software-recommendation, power-management

I'm trying to install the Jupiter power settings app but, I read it is no longer compatible with the new kernel. Is there a similar program or a way to manage the power settings on 13.04?

Comment: Would be hard to get Jupiter source-code and update it to work with newer kernels? Any tips where i should start? I know Java and a little bit of Python.

Comment: I run 13.04, and jupiter still runs fine.

Comment: may want to look into Slim: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/05/slimbook-battery-optimizer-ubuntu

Comment: Try [CPU Power Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/) GNOME extension.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

## [Improve Power  Usage / Battery Life In Linux With TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)

### Overview

TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to fulfil your specific requirements.

### Features

```
Kernel laptop mode and dirty buffer timeouts
Processor frequency scaling including "turbo boost" / "turbo core"
Power aware process scheduler for multi-core/hyper-threading
Hard disk advanced power magement level and spin down timeout (per disk)
SATA aggressive link power management (ALPM)
PCI Express active state power management (PCIe ASPM) – Linux 2.6.35 and above
Runtime power management for PCI(e) bus devices – Linux 2.6.35 and above
Radeon KMS power management – Linux 2.6.35 and above, not fglrx
Radeon dynamic power management – Kernel 3.11 and above, not fglrx
Wifi power saving mode – depending on kernel/driver
Power off optical drive in drive bay (on battery)
Audio power saving mode – hda_intel, ac97
```

[Also Check Additional functions](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#features)

### Installation

[Also Check Prerequisites](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

#### ThinkPads

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

- **tlp-rdw** – Radio Device Wizard - Need to enable/disable & Power saving (Wifi / Bluetooth )
- **smartmontools** - needed by tlp-stat to display disk drive S.M.A.R.T. data
- **ethtool** - needed to disable wake on lan
- **tp-smapi-dkms** ThinkPad only, tp-smapi is needed for battery charge thresholds and ThinkPad specific status output of tlp-stat
- **acpi-call-tools** ThinkPad only, acpi-call is needed for battery charge thresholds on Sandy Bridge and newer models

---

### Additional

**TLP Indicator for Unity**
A Unity Indicator created to comfortably switch between AC and BAT Modes.
Use it at your own risk.
Download here: [indicator-TLP.py](https://github.com/silverjam/Sysmods/blob/master/scripts/indicator-TLP.py)

[image: TLP Indicator for Unity]

---

### Configuration

Removing default Ubuntu cpu frequency config

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove
```

#### TLP Developer

( This is not a general prerequisite for TLP but is only needed **if the user decides** to change the default governor. If a user issues the command **without changing the TLP setting** too, he ends up with "perfomance", which is quite bad for battery life.), Apply to section **3.)** Processor and Frequency Scaling

The main config file of TLP is at /etc/default/tlp

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

---

### Parameters

#### General hints

1. Parameters ending on _AC are effective with the power supply connected
2. Parameters ending on _BAT are effective when running on battery
3. Parameters containing blanks must be enclosed in double quotes like this: ""
4. Some parameters are inactive by default; remove the leading '#' to activate

---

#### 0.) **General**

```
TLP_ENABLE=1
```

Set to 0 to disable TLP (Reboot needed), It should be enabled so leave the default value

#### 1.) **File System**

```
   DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
   DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
```

DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2 = You can either leave the default value **(2)** or you can edit it as **5**, By default Ubuntu uses **5**, its up to you, read the gives below help

```
cat /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode
```

This controls how agressive the system is at trying to avoid
writing to disk.  The longer the disk is idle, the more power you can save.

This is only active on battery power, and it restores these values
to kernel defaults when on AC power.

**Defaults 5**, which enables laptop mode and forces the system to **wait 
5 seconds** whenever something asks to write to disk to flush out as much
data as we can.

#### 2.) **Dirty page values**

```
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
```

Leave the default value

Defaults 60, which means that the kernel will not start forcing process
to write out file information that has been changed but not saved until 60%
of usable system memory is filled with dirty information.

#### 3.) **Processor and Frequency Scaling**

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=ondemand
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave
```

Remove the hash and edit it as conservative.

Its up to you what you want, you can also use **ON_BAT=powersave**

Select a cpu frequency scaling governor: ondemand/powersave/performance/conservative

**Governor ??**

The governor decides what frequency should be used.

Module Description:

```
ondemand        Dynamically switch between CPU(s) available if at 95% cpu load

performance     Run the cpu at max frequency

conservative    Dynamically switch between CPU(s) available if at 75% load

powersave       Run the cpu at the minimum frequency
```

**TLP Developer**

To use "conservative" over "powersave – especially on AC – should not be
a general recommendation but only an option for hardware that produces
excessive heat or fan noise.

#### 4.) **Min/Max frequency**

```
#CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
#CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
```

Set the min/max frequency available for the scaling governor.
Possible values strongly depend on your cpu. For available frequencies see 
tlp-stat output, Section "+++ Processor".

**Hint**: Parameters are disabled by default, remove the leading # to enable them,
otherwise kernel default values are used.

#### 5.) **Turbo Boost**

```
CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
```

Set the cpu "turbo boost" feature: 0=disable / 1=allow ,Requires an Intel Core i processor and kernel 3.7 or later.

**Important:**
This may conflict with your distribution's governor settings, A value of 1 does *not* activate boosting, it just allows it

#### 6.) **Cpu Cores/Hyper-Threads**

```
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
```

Minimize number of used cpu cores/hyper-threads under light load conditions

#### 7.) **Kernel**

```
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
```

Activate kernel NMI watchdog timer (0 = disabled/save power, 1=enabled). A value of 1 is relevant for kernel debugging only.

#### 8.) **Hard disk advanced power management level**

```
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
```

Set the "Advanced Power Management Level". Possible values range between 1 and 255:

```
1 – max power saving / minimum performance
```

Important: this setting may lead to increased disk drive wear and tear because of excessive read-write head unloading (recognizable from the clicking noises)

```
128 – compromise between power saving and wear (TLP standard setting on battery)

192 – prevents excessive head unloading of some HDDs

254 – minimum power saving / max performance (TLP standard setting on ac)

255 – disable APM (not supported by some disk models)
```

Different values for multiple disks are separated with blanks.

#### 9.) **Disk I/O Scheduler**

```
#DISK_IOSCHED="cfq cfq"
```

Select io scheduler for the disk devices: noop/deadline/cfq (Default: cfq) 
Separate values for multiple devices with spaces.

**noop** is often the best choice for memory-backed block devices (e.g. ramdisks) and other non-rotational media (flash) where trying to reschedule I/O is a waste of resources

**deadline** is a lightweight scheduler which tries to put a hard limit on latency

**cfq** tries to maintain system-wide fairness of I/O bandwidth

#### 10.) **SATA aggressive link power management** (ALPM):

min_power/medium_power/max_performance

```
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
```

**ALPM**
Aggressive Link Power Management (ALPM) is a mechanism where a SATA AHCI controller can put the SATA link that connects to the disk into a very low power mode during periods of zero I/O activity and into an active power state when work needs to be done. Tests show that this can save around 0.5-1.5 Watts of power on a typical system. ( For more check **" Sources and additional help "** )

#### 11.) **PCI Express Active State Power Management** (PCIe ASPM):

( default/performance/powersave )

**Hint:** needs kernel boot option pcie_aspm=force on some machines

```
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
```

#### 12.) **Radeon graphics clock speed**

(profile method): low/mid/high/auto/default

auto = mid on BAT, high on AC; default = use hardware defaults (Kernel >= 2.6.35 only, not with fglrx driver!)

```
#RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
#RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
```

#### 13.) **WiFi power saving mode**

1=disable/5=enable

(Linux 2.6.32 and later, some adapters only!)

```
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
```

#### 14.) **Disable wake on lan**

Y = Yes , N = No

```
WOL_DISABLE=Y
```

#### 15.) **Audio power saving for Intel HDA**

Enable audio power saving for Intel HDA, AC97 devices (timeout in secs). A value of 0 disables / >=1 enables power save.

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE=1
```

> Disable controller too (HDA only): Y/N

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
```

#### 16.) **Power off optical drive in UltraBay** >> **(ThinkPads only)**

Set to 1 to power off optical drive in UltraBay (ThinkPads only), when running on battery. A value of 0 disables this Feature (Default). Drive can be powered on again by releasing (and reinserting) the eject lever or by pressing the disc eject button on newer models. **Note**: an UltraBay hard disk is never powered off.

```
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=1
```

> Optical drive device to power off (default sr0)

```
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
```

#### 17.) **Runtime Power Management for pci(e) bus devices**

```
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
```

> **Runtime PM for *all* pci(e) bus devices**

```
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
```

Runtime PM for *all* pci(e) bus devices: 0=disable / 1=enable, Warning: experimental option, could cause system instabilities

Some times my usb mouse dongle didn't work when i plug it in usb 3 port, work fine when i plug it in usb 2 port, and all my usb 3 devices are working properly no issue.

#### 18.) **Usb autosuspend**

Set to 0 to disable/1 to enable usb autosuspend feature

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
```

#### 19.) **System Start and Shutdown**

```
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0
```

Restores radio device state (builtin bluetooth, wifi, wwan) from previous shutdown on system startup:

0 – disable, 1 – enable

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"
```

Disables builtin radio devices upon system start:

```
bluetooth
wifi – Wireless LAN
wwan – Wireless Wide Area Network (UMTS)
```

Multiple devices are separated with blanks.

I have an error that my **Blue tooth** device is not Disabled on start up, so if you face this problem just do the following config

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And add the following line before exit 0

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

**Save & Exit & Reboot**

---

### Working with TLP

After installation TLP will be automatically activated upon system start.

To start it immediately without reboot or to apply changed settings use:

```
sudo tlp start
```

Use the tlp-stat terminal command to check if TLP is working properly

```
sudo tlp-stat
```

Check You system temperature

```
sudo tlp-stat -t
```

Show battery information only:

```
sudo tlp-stat -b
sudo tlp-stat --battery
```

Show configuration only:

```
tlp-stat -c
tlp-stat --config
```

Show radio devices switch state only:

```
tlp-stat -r
tlp-stat --rfkill
```

Show temperatures and fan speed only:

```
tlp-stat -t
```

Apply Battery Settings (ignoring the actual power source):

```
sudo tlp bat
```

Apply AC Settings (ignoring the actual power source):

```
sudo tlp ac
```

You can check Which I/O you are using.

```
sudo tlp-stat  # Check the section +++ Storage Devices
```

---

#### Trace Mode

To examine suspected problems in TLP more closely, activate trace mode in /etc/default/tlp:

```
TLP_DEBUG="lock nm path pm rf run sysfs udev usb"
```

Add above mentioned line in the end /etc/default/tlp , The accumulated trace data may be read at any time with

```
tlp-stat -T
```

Or

```
grep "tlp" /var/log/debug
```

In case the trace output is missing, you have to modify your rsyslogd configuration. Create the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/90-debug.conf` containing

```
*.=debug;\
auth,authpriv.none;\
news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
```

And restart the daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

---

### Sources and additional help

[There is very good support at TLP Website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

[Useful Config Link 1](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html)

[TLP Settings](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)

[ALPM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementALPM)

---

## Optional tweaks

### Tweak your CPU frequency with `indicator-cpufreq`

#### Installation

`indicator-cpufreq` will help you change your CPU frequency on the go:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Go to *Dash* > search for *Startup* > edit `indicator-cpufreq` add `-f` or copy paste the following command:

```
indicator-cpufreq -f
```

[image]

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

With the indicator you will be able to monitor your current CPU frequency & can change CPU frequency

#### Changing CPU frequency

Click on indicator

[image: screenshot]

- ### Additional Advice
- #### VA-API (Hardware Acceleration For Intel / AMD GPUs)

### Overview

The main motivation for VA-API (Video Acceleration API) is to enable hardware accelerated video decode/encode at various entry-points (VLD, IDCT, Motion Compensation etc.) for the prevailing coding standards today (MPEG-2, MPEG-4 ASP/H.263, MPEG-4 AVC/H.264, and VC-1/VMW3). Extending XvMC was considered, but due to its original design for MPEG-2 MotionComp only, it made more sense to design an interface from scratch that can fully expose the video decode capabilities in today's GPUs.

- Help full Links
- [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-mplayer-with-va-api-hardware.html)

[Official Intel Drivers are using VA-API](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/2013q1-intel-graphics-stack-release)

[Support video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API)

### Install Intel / AMD VA-API drivers in Ubuntu

#### for Intel GPUs (for Intel HD Graphics as well as G45 and later):

```
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo
```

#### for AMD Radeon GPUs (you also need the proprietary drivers!):

```
sudo apt-get install xvba-va-driver vainfo
```

> **Install MPlayer with VA-API support in Ubuntu**

By default, the MPlayer version available in the official Ubuntu repositories doesn't support VA-API, but you can use a PPA which provides custom MPlayer builds with VA-API support.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sander-vangrieken/vaapi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mplayer-vaapi
```

Now you need to install **smplayer or vlc**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

### OR

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

### Configuration

**SMPLAYER**

Its in **Option tab** > Preferences, on the Video tab > General Video > Output driver set the video output driver to "vaapi":

[image: screenshot]

**VLC**

Its in Tools > Preferences > Input & Codecs > Enable **Use GPU Accelerated decoding**

[image]

Helpful Links

- [How to correctly enable/test VA-API on Intel Sandy Bridge?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247911/how-to-correctly-enable-test-va-api-on-intel-sandy-bridge)
- [Command line flag for mplayer to use hardware acceleration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101948/command-line-flag-for-mplayer-to-use-hardware-acceleration/126723#126723)

---

### PowerSavingTweaks for Intel Graphics

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"
```

and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Helpful Links

- [3x+ battery life](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134109)

Comment: +1, Very comprehensive answer! TLP would be my tool of choice as well. Maybe you could add that TLP can be started and stopped with `sudo tlp start` / `sudo tlp stop` and that you can also manually switch between different power modes with `sudo tlp bat` / `sudo tlp ac`.

Comment: Oh, and as a powersaving-phobist you might also want to check out `powertop`, which can check current power usage and verify that TLP is helping.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent check my answer please

Comment: Looks as if you've covered everything. Great work, man! As for the global answer, I think it's a fantastic idea. It's hard to come by good overviews as yours.

Comment: Discharging your battery completely on modern laptops can be damaging the battery: http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html#descBat There are many more sources for this, please google "battery discharge myth"

Comment: 1 thing I hate about TLP... it is not the most left side indicator. Transmission is. So every time the CPU toggles the processor speed transmission indicator goes from left to right and from right to left. VERY annoying.

Comment: @Rinzwind Then do not use -f option indicator-cpufreq , just leave the standard...

Comment: It seems there is additional unneeded quote in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915`

Comment: I want to draw on your expertise to solve a problem asked before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/303800/shutdown-slow-in-13-04-hangs-on-shutting-down-processes It looks like tlp does not use upstart, but sysvinit. This causes the shutdown process to slow because of a sysvinit fail. Is there a way to make tlp use upstart? Thanks.

Comment: Discharging a Li-Ion battery on purpose just reduces its lifetime. The recommendation to discharge it twice a week is __complete bullshit.__

Comment: @Qasim can you clear up old, inaccurate information? This is too long to be read easily.

Comment: @Braiam, I will try to do it soon ( new feature ). I been testing things on 14.04 & will update ASAP.

Comment: Ok, remember to remove obsolete information to keep it tidy.

Comment: you state it's only for unity but on the faq of the developper i can read : "all features of TLP are independent of the desktop environment"  http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html (maybe you should update i've almost discarded tlp for my gnome desktop...)

Comment: But how do I put this in sleep mode and wake it up from sleep mode?

Comment: Did this have any effect in 14.04? I installed it and everything seemed the same. I use `powertop --auto-tune` at systemstart, so maybe I already had everything optimized before?

Comment: Yes it does, you need to install package powerstat and then check it power usage with powerstat -d 0 @rubo77

Comment: **Indicator-TLP** is no longer available in the address specified in the answer, but it can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silverjam/Sysmods/master/scripts/indicator-TLP.py

Comment: Don't want to be repetitive but, did this have any effect in 16.04? Could be better powertop?

Comment: There is a typo of additional `"` before `'quiet splash'` in the grub command above, which gives the error "/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 36: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution". Should be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"`

Comment: So what happens if indicator-cpufreq says `performance` but tlp says `bat`?  Do I need to manually change to `powersave` in the indicator-cpufreq menu every time I disconnect my laptop from AC?

Comment: Running `sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove` gives me `insserv: script mysql.server: service mysql already provided!` Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: starting with Ubuntu Wily 15, TLP  is provided via the official Ubuntu repos

Answer (score 10):

This is what I read in [7 Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html):

> Jupiter used to be one of the first things to install after a fresh
>   Ubuntu installation, but unfortunately the application has been
>   discontinued and the old version doesn't work properly in Ubuntu
>   13.04.
>
> But, if battery life is what you're interested in, you can use TLP, a
>   tool that you install and then forget about it because it
>   automatically tweaks your system for better power usage / battery
>   life.
>
> To install TLP in Ubuntu 13.04, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw   
sudo tlp start
```

I have no personal experience of TLP.

Comment: Homepage: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

Comment: i been using tlp from few days and my laptop is 4 to 6 deg Cooler then windows

Answer (score 4):

Jupiter for 13.04 has arrived!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jolicloud-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Comment: Note this will probably ponly work for 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04: https://launchpad.net/~jolicloud-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 2):

1. PowerTOP is a Linux tool to diagnose issues with power consumption and power management.

   In addition to being a diagnostic tool, PowerTOP also has an interactive mode where the user can experiment various power management settings for cases where the Linux distribution has not enabled these settings.
2. This udev tool enables the most aggressive power saving settings automaticly:

/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local-powersave.rules

```
# PCI runtime power management
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# USB autosuspend
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/autosuspend" ATTR{power/autosuspend}="60"

# SATA active link power management
SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host", KERNEL=="host*", ATTR{link_power_management_policy}="min_power"

# Wlan power save
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan*" RUN+="/usr/sbin/iw dev %k set power_save on"

# Disable bluetooth
SUBSYSTEM=="rfkill", ATTR{type}=="bluetooth", ATTR{state}="0"

# Disable wake-on-LAN
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth*" RUN+="/usr/sbin/ethtool -s %k wol d"
```

Comment: powertop is a nice tool, but the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local-powersave.rules` doesn't exist in 14.04 any more, what about those setting you posted here? I use `powertop --auto-tune` to tune everything

Comment: You can create this file by yourself.

Comment: So do you need powertop? Or are you suggesting two different things?

Comment: No you don't need powertop to use this config.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'd like to add [auto-cpufreq](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq) to the list. It's a new automatic CPU speed and power optimization tool for Linux laptops using Intel CPUs. Support for AMD CPUs is being worked on.

This command line tool automatically changes the CPU frequency scaling, governor (switches between performance and powersave, these being the only 2 modes supported by the nowadays default intel_pstate scaling driver) and turbo boost status based on various information gathered from your computer, like the battery state, CPU usage and system load. (source: [Linux Uprising](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/auto-cpufreq-is-new-cpu-speed-and-power.html))

The installation instructions below come from its Github page:

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt install git python3-dev python3-pip python3-distro python3-psutil python3-click python3-power -y
```

On Ubuntu versions older than 19.10:

```
pip3 install --upgrade psutil click distro power
```

Grab auto-cpufreq from Git:

```
git clone https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq.git
```

Run auto-cpufreq

```
cd auto-cpufreq

sudo python3 auto-cpufreq.py --live
```

--live enables auto-cpufreq so you can see how your system behaves with the new settings, but it doesn't make these settings permanent.

To make it permanent, use the --install option (so the changes persist across reboots; this installs the auto-cpufreq daemon and systemd service):

```
sudo python3 auto-cpufreq.py --install
```